# Oracle SQL Developer - Help for debugging

Tags: oracle, debugging, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

I am trying to debug a package with in the SQL Developer. The method that i am trying to debug takes 2 parameters

```
PROCEDURE procedure_name (dblink IN CHAR, bDebug IN BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE)
```

When i click on "Debug" icon, it asks for inputs that i need to give to this procedure. I give

```
dblink:='linkname';
bDebug:=TRUE;
```

but when it starts debugging, I see the value of dblink as

```
 'linkname                                                   
 '
```

i.e. linkname, lots of spaces and then the ending quote. so when in code i try to do this

```
`strSrc VARCHAR(120) := 'tablename'||dblink;`
```

it gives me error that buffer is to small, which makes sense. but why SQL Developer is doing so? how to fix it?

Comment: Is there a reason the parameter is declared as `CHAR` instead of `VARCHAR2`? I suspect that's where the padding is coming from.

Comment: I am not sure why it has been declared as `CHAR` instead of `VARCHAR`. But its in production, so i don't think that i can change it for current debugging ---- my only concern is the padding.

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing your padding is coming from how SQL Developer is defining its variable to bind with (it is probably defining it as a CHAR(4000)).  For now, you should be able to get around this in your test code by putting trim() around the dblink variable:

```
strSrc VARCHAR(120) := 'tablename'||trim(dblink);
```

Note that this would normally not be needed if the procedure was passed a literal (or a correctly sized CHAR variable, a VARCHAR, etc), like the production code is probably doing.

Comment: I am already using the trimming function but for that i had to modify code. as i told earlier that the code is in production already and i don't want to change the code.

Answer (score 0):

For debugging purposes, create a wrapper procedure that accepts a VARCHAR2 parameter, then passes it to your procedure; then you debug it in SQL Developer by calling your wrapper.